# Disable default error page in Tomcat for Spring MVC REST API

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC 3.2 @RequestMapping and @ResponseBody as REST Service. A example endpoint looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "query", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Locations searchHandler(@RequestParam String q, HttpServletRequest request,     HttpServletResponse response) {
...
```

Sending a wrong request for non existing endpoints or missing GET parameter q will show the Tomcat 7 error report:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.50 - Error report</title>
        <style>
            <!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}-->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>HTTP Status 404 - </h1>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
            <p>
                <b>type</b> Status report
            </p>
            <p>
                <b>message</b>
                <u></u>
            </p>
            <p>
                <b>description</b>
                <u>The requested resource is not available.</u>
            </p>
            <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
                <h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.50</h3>
            </body>
        </html>
```

How can I disable this error page. I just want the error message as content without any HTML or further informations.

Answer (score 4):

Ok I found the Solution. I implemented a Exception handler as described in the link above:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorController {

    /**
     * .
     * @param request .
     * @param response .
     * @throws Exception .
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public void handleConflict(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Exception e) throws Exception {
        // If the exception is annotated with @ResponseStatus rethrow it and let
        // the framework handle it - like the OrderNotFoundException example
        // at the start of this post.
        // AnnotationUtils is a Spring Framework utility class.
        if (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(e.getClass(), ResponseStatus.class) != null) {
            throw e;
        }

        response.setStatus(400);
        response.getWriter().println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Its important to use response.getWriter()... instead of using response.sendError().